# Json Response exception

Tags: java, json

I get this exception while using json

`json: com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.JSONRPC2ParseException: Invalid JSON-RPC 2.0:`

Version string missing? 
Im getting exception at the below line:

```
JSONRPC2Response response = session.send(requestOut);
```

Here is my code:

```
JSONRPC2Session session = new JSONRPC2Session(endPointURL);
        JSONRPC2SessionOptions options=session.getOptions();
        ///options.setRequestContentType("text/html");
        options.setAllowedResponseContentTypes(new String[]{"text/html; charset=UTF-8"});



        String method = "Request";
        String timestamp=PaymentStringUtil.gofTimeStamp();
        Map<String, Object> reqParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        reqParams.put("words", StringUtil.sha1("SA3PROU","a8affe42f8bbc90621762c53fd973bceee175db2","20140120100821"));
        reqParams.put("tourcode", "SA3PROU");
        reqParams.put("timestamp","20140120100821");



        System.out.println(reqParams);

        JSONRPC2Request requestOut = new JSONRPC2Request(method,reqParams,1);
        System.out.println(requestOut);
        try {
            System.out.println("Inside try-----------");

            JSONRPC2Response response = session.send(requestOut);
            //System.out.println(session.send(requestOut));


            System.out.println(response.indicatesSuccess());
            if (response.indicatesSuccess()) {




        System.out.println("Inside the indicate success");
                JSONParser jsonParser =new JSONParser();
                JSONObject jsonObject=(JSONObject)jsonParser.parse(response.getResult().toString());
                JSONObject response=(JSONObject)jsonObject.get("Request");
                //set the response obj
            } else {
                System.out.println("Outside the indicate success");
                System.out.println(response.getError().getMessage());

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();


        }

        return response;
    }
```

Here is the stack trace:

Invalid JSON-RPC 2.0 response
com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.client.JSONRPC2SessionException: Invalid JSON-RPC 2.0 response
    at com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.client.JSONRPC2Session.send(JSONRPC2Session.java:586)
    at com.garuda.api.test.Configure.requestProvider(Configure.java:81)
    at com.garuda.api.test.Configure.main(Configure.java:128)
Caused by: com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.JSONRPC2ParseException: Invalid JSON-RPC 2.0: Version string missing
    at com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.JSONRPC2Parser.ensureVersion2(JSONRPC2Parser.java:236)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.JSONRPC2Parser.parseJSONRPC2Response(JSONRPC2Parser.java:481)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.JSONRPC2Response.parse(JSONRPC2Response.java:229)
    at com.thetransactioncompany.jsonrpc2.client.JSONRPC2Session.send(JSONRPC2Session.java:579)
    ... 2 more

Comment: Show us your code and the response string. Else, noone will be able to help you. I assume, that your Response is not in a correct format.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code of JSONRPC2Parser](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/files/jsonrpc2base/javadoc/src-html/com/thetransactioncompany/jsonrpc2/JSONRPC2Parser.html) the version for JSON-RPC 2.0 must be present in the request object in the jsonrpc member. If it is not present at all you get the error you are describing. According to the [JSON-RPC 2.0 specification](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification#request_object) the version must be present and be `2.0`.

Comment: It is present in the request message.

Comment: Do you get any stacktrace? I am trying to follow the code and I see there being a method for adding jsonrpc, but I can't see it actually calling that method.

Comment: Im simply calling the method from main method.

Comment: But you have the request message somewhere? You said that jsonrpc is present in the request message.

Comment: it automatically gets added to the request parameter.if you print the request parameters yo get this:

Comment: {"id":1,"method":"salesAgentRequest","params":{"timestamp":"20140120100821","words":"fc0f14731d2b9df93d3d949eba508df85e98d574","tourcode":"SA3PROU"},"jsonrpc":"2.0"}

Comment: Interesting, so you have the jsonrpc parameter, but the parser complains about it being missing. Can you try parsing this json directly using the parser?